# Scala Play 2.4 view render vs apply

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I notice both `views.html.myView.render(...)` and `views.html.myView(...)` can be used to generate a page from the template. However, in case that we need to pass a implicit parameter list into the view, it seems only the `apply` version works while the `render` version does not compile.

I assume `views.html.myView.apply` probably delegates to `views.html.myView.render` (or the other way around) behind the scene, but I'm not sure and can't find anything related to this in the documentation. The only thing I can get from the Twirl documentation is that `TemplateN` traits all define the `render` method, but none of them mention `apply`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `render` method is meant to be used from Java, and `apply` is meant to be used from Scala. Render delegates to `apply`, and they will have exactly the same signatures *unless* there are multiple parameter lists (from currying or implicits).

Let's say I have `index.html.scala` from the play-scala activator template, modified to add an implicit `Int` parameter:

```
@(message: String)(implicit i: Int)
```

It will get compiled to `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/views/html/index.template.scala`. Here are the relevant pieces:

```
def apply(message: String)(implicit i: Int): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = ...

def render(message: String, i: Int): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable =
    apply(message)(i)
```

The parameters in `render` are squashed into a single list. Since you cannot use implicits from Java (or multiple parameter lists), they need to be explicitly passed in a single list.

If I remove the implicit, they are the same:

```
def apply(message: String): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = ...

def render(message:String): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = apply(message)
```

Comment: Nice answer! That explains why `render` does not compile although I have the appropriate implicits in scope.